# How can I pass quoted strings as arguments to functions in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a simple bash function whose goal is to run a command passed in as a string, check the return code in $?, and if it returns nonzero, print an error specified in the second argument and exit.

Here's the function:

```
function checkcommand()
{
    $1
    if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
        echo "$2"
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

The function works great.  Here are some examples that work:

```
checkcommand "git clone /home/git/framework.git $gitreponame" "git clone failed!
"
```

The problem comes when I want to use my function to validate the success of a commit:

```
checkcommand "git commit -m\"remove migrations from release-$todaysrelease-pr
ep\"" "Commit for migrations removal from release-$todaysrelease-prep failed!"
```

I've tried (as pictured) baclslash quoting, single quotes, various combos of single and double quotes, etc.

Thanks for any clues!

Comment: What version of bash/sh/whatever are you using? It works under _GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)_ and _GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)_

Comment: Related: [How do I use a Bash variable (string) containing quotes in a command?](https://superuser.com/q/360966/11574)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function checkcommand()
{
    eval $1
    if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
        echo "$2"
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

Use `\` before `"` in your command as you did in your example.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! I knew about eval, but hadn't thought about using it in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Leave word lists as word lists; don't quote them up into a single word only to expand it out later: eval is evil.

The typical `die` function is a much simpler and much more readable idiom:

```
die() {
  echo "$*" >&2
  exit 1
}

git commit -m"remove migrations from release-$todaysrelease-prep" ||
  die "Commit for migrations removal from release-$todaysrelease-prep failed!"
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "eval is evil, especially in this context?

Comment: @feoh For your example checkcommand "git clone /home/git/framework.git $gitreponame", what would happen if gitreponame=";rm -rf .git"?

Comment: @MarkEdgar a little late in responding, but in case you didn't read the question, the requirement is to pass the command as a string which means the command could be anything. How do you suggest running a string as a command (if it really is) without using `eval`.